# list cannot be applied to boolean android

Tags: android

I want to draw boolean data from the database, but my code is wrong. How do I assign boolean data to the getstate variable? I want to assign the data in the database to the getstate variable in the product class. How do I do it?
I get this error on the line :

> productList.add(p.getStates());

: I am getting the error:

> list cannot be applied to boolean

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final   DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("states");
    List<Product> productList;

dbProducts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                productList = new ArrayList<>();

                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    for(DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Product p = productSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                        productList.add(p);
                    }
                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            Product p = snapshot.getValue(Product.class);

                            productList.add(p.getStates());
                       }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });

public class Product {

    private String places;
    private String time;
    private String title;
    private String id;
    private boolean States;

    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(String places, String time, String title, String id, boolean States) {
        this.places = places;
        this.time = time;
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
        this.States = States;

    }

    public String getplaces() {
        return places;
    }

    public String gettime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String gettitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean getStates() {
        return States;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a Boolean value in a list that cotains a Product. The correct way to do it is:

```
productList.add(p);
```

Comment: I just want to assign the variable getStates.

Comment: The var States is in the object Product so If you add product in the productsList then you can access in getStates of any object in the list

Comment: What should I do? Just to throw it at getStates?

Comment: If you add product in productList as I said you can make a loop where you need it and access in State variable: product.getState()